# Why does SSMS show different versions of SQL for the same synapse database

Tags: azure-synapse

I am doing online studying for an exam and I have created a synapse workspace with an admin user named sqladminuser which I am using to connect to it by using SQL Authentication.  I took the database off pause and I couldn't see the tables.  If I connect using Azure Active Directory using MFA and my own user account - I can see the tables.  I can run queries against both databases and get results but I want to know

1 - Why does it show have having a different synapse version in SSMS?

2 - Why won't it show the tables on the sqladminuser as it is the SQL Admin account?

3 - Can I change it so that I can see the tables using the SQL Authentication?  If so how?

Any and all help much appreciated?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it show have having a different synapse version in SSMS?

We tried in our environment and both the logins it is showing same SQL version and tables.

[image]

This can be becaues of multiple instencer or versions are installed on your system.

> Why won't it show the tables on the sqladminuser as it is the SQL Admin account?

- Verify whether the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission has a DENY setting.
- Refresh in object explorer because SSMS does not do it automatically we need to do it manually.

> Can I change it so that I can see the tables using the SQL Authentication? If so how?

At the database level, provide the user access to "**View Definition**"

**Right click on the database name >> Properties >> Permissions >> select the user >> Click on "View Definition" checkbox.** This will let the user view the Tables or views.